# Como manter uma planilha oculta ao abrir outro arquivo excel? (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

No código da pasta de trabalho, tenho o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
    Userform1.show
End Sub
```

Funciona perfeitamente, ou seja, ao abrir a planilha, a mesma fica oculta e exibe somente a userform criada. Porém, caso eu abra outro arquivo Excel enquanto a userform está sendo exibida, a aplicação (Planilha de fundo onde foi criada a userform) volta a ser exibida. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso? Preciso que a planilha permaneça oculta.

Comment: Um conselho: busque material sobre como criar extensões (add-ins, em inglês) para Excel. Você consegue criá-las com VBA, e inclusive consegue inserir barras com botões personalizados no menu do Excel. Você pode também brincar de setar a propriedade `IsAddin` da sua pasta de trabalho como `true`; ele vai desaparecer e não aparecerá até que seja setado como `false`; isso deve funcionar para você (vai ocultar o arquivo inteiro, não apenas uma planilha).